# Change the state for multiple components in react

Tags: reactjs

```
state={value:false,value1:true}


<Switch 
          id="1"
          isOn={this.state.value}
          onColor="rgb(116, 194, 116)"
          handleToggle={() => this.setState({value:!this.state.value})}
          />

<Switch 
          id="2"
          isOn={this.state.value1}
          onColor="rgb(116, 194, 116)"
          handleToggle={() => this.setState({value1:!this.state.value1})}
          />
```

the handletoggler in switch 2 is changing the state for switch 1. how do i use this?

Comment: `how do i use this?` your question is not clear. Please, specify what do you want to solve?

Comment: the setState func in second switch is not changing value1 in the state

Comment: could you create an example on https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-almeida-wukgf?file=/src/switch.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon checking the codesandbox, I noticed you are passing `id` from your App.js but not consuming it in switch.js, thus the label is attaching itself to the first  input because the ID is hardcoded.

**switch.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Switch = ({ isOn, handleToggle, onColor, id }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        checked={isOn}
        onChange={handleToggle}
        className="react-switch-checkbox"
        id={id}
        type="checkbox"
      />
      <label
        style={{ background: isOn && onColor }}
        className="react-switch-label"
        htmlFor={id}
      >
        <span className={`react-switch-button`} />
      </label>
    </>
  );
};
export default Switch;
```